# Как поменять ширину скролла? Css и с плагинам не получается. Что получается видно на картинке, только зеленый скролл нужно шириной 52px

Tags: css

```css
.table {
       width: 1570px;
        overflow: hidden;
        overflow-x: auto;
} 
.table::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 4px;
        width: 52px;
}
.table::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: rgb(194, 192, 190);
}
.table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: green;
        border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="table">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ereJq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает как надо. Просто Вы задаёте обертке ширину, ей же стилизацию скроллов, но при этом эти скроллы там никогда не появятся. Показывается внешний скролл, стили которого не определены.

В примере ниже показано, как работает стилизация скроллов (только Chromium-подобные браузеры), если таблица имеет размеры большие, чем обертка:

```css
.table {
       width: 1570px;
       height: 250px;
        overflow-x: auto;
} 
.table::-webkit-scrollbar {
        height: 4px;
        width: 52px;
}
.table::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: rgb(194, 192, 190);
}
.table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: green;
        border-radius: 5px;
}

.table-body {
width: 2000px;
height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
                <table class="table-body">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>1</th>
                            <th>1</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Владимир за помощь, но только горизонтальная полоса, как стандартной длины была, так и осталась(

Comment: @YulyaSu Что Вы имеете в виду под длиной?

Comment: Я имею ввиду сделать ширину зеленого скролла меньше, чем идущей по умолчанию. В картинке прикрепленной к вопросу посмотрите пожалуйста, так более нагляднее будет.

Comment: @YulyaSu Ну так и есть же https://i.imgur.com/JewedUU.png